# Resharper upgrade from VS2010 to VS2019. Where does the UserSettings.xml or resharper xml file reside for code clean up and custom patterns?

Tags: c#, resharper

We are upgrading from an older verion of resharper in Visual studio 2010 to Resharper 2020 in VIsual studo 2019.
Where does the UserSettings.xml or resharper xml file reside? This file contains code clean up profile, some code for regions. Is it that in the newer versions they have a .Dotsettings file instead of xml file?

[image]

In the previous version it looked like this. We have a file called UserSettings.xml which has mostly all resharper settings. How do I attach the  new resharper to load settings from the same xml file.

[image]

Custom Patterns.
[image]

Comment: It is unlikely that the old ReSharper 5.1 settings will work with the latest ReSharper (2020.2). If you have more than one machine then I would suggest upgrading one and configure it as best you can to match your old settings on the other.

Comment: @PiersMyers: I configured the code clean up settings and made a new code clean up profile. We have additional custom patterns for adding regions with Ctrl+E+F. There is a button in reshaper to import custom patterns from resharper 6 and below.  When I click on import, it takes an xml file.. But I don't see any patterns being loaded.